# Hide dialog in kotlin on certain conditions

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible to achieve this in Kotlin Android studio.

I have two alert dialog

Dialog one shows on one event to notify users that the event is loading.

Dialog 2 shows when the first event finish loading.

**The current results, if dialog one shows, within 2 seconds the activity finish loading and then shows dialog 2.**

How can I hide dialog one, on condition of when dialog 2 shows?

This is my alert dialog code

```
AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
                        .setTitle("Status upload")
                        .setMessage("Your image was successfully uploaded!") // Specifying a listener allows you to take an action before dismissing the dialog.
                        // The dialog is automatically dismissed when a dialog button is clicked.
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes) { dialog, which ->
                            // Continue with delete operation
                        } // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.

                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_check_success)
                        .show()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this where the event ends

> dialog1.dismiss()

Comment: Looks simple, but how will android know Dialog1

Comment: Dialog1 is the reference name of your dialog instance. @BluechipServers

Comment: I have added my alert dialog code what will be the reference for instance